# How to block access to directory listing and certain pages in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have several issues with how I am configuring my web.config due to my inexperience.

I want to set a page, login.aspx, as my default page. If the user logs in successfully, he will be redirected to a page in a protected folder /Protect/Edit.aspx . All users can still access a page in root folder named Show.aspx, will be redirected to login.aspx if they try to click or write the path to Edit.aspx, and I am unsure on how to do this.

My other problem is that if I write just localhost it shows me the directory listing, and I want to avoid this, but setting

still gives me the directory listing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a session variable.Store user name or id in it.If its not null allow user to access page else redirect then to Login.aspx

Comment: Yes, that is one way. But as I am told, that is a naive approach. I still cannot allow absolutely nobody to see the contents in the folder if they are not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to implement forms authentification for your app. Here is a [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240)
2. Seems like you don't have a default.aspx page, so IIS couldn't find any document to load first. You can either configure IIS to use Show.aspx as a default page, or just add default .aspx.